# Micropython error : OSError: [Errno 19] ENODEV

Tags: micropython

I am trying to use pressure sensors and a LOLIN D32 pro microcontroller to measure water level. The two pressure sensors are MS5803 and BME280 below is my code

'''

```
import machine        
from machine import Pin, I2C        
import bme280, ms5803        
import time        

i2c= I2C(scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(21), freq=10000)        
bme1 = bme280.BME280(i2c=i2c, address = 119)        
BuiltinLED = machine.Pin(5, Pin.OUT)         
BuiltinLED.value(1)         
WaterLevelDifference=0        

def depth():       
    [T1,P1,H1] = bme1.raw_values      #T in degrees C, P in hPa        
    [P2,T2] = ms5803.read(i2c=i2c, address = 118)        
    WaterLevelDifference = ((P2-P1)*100/9810)                
    return WaterLevelDifference         
depth()        
while WaterLevelDifference<100:        
    if WaterLevelDifference > 0.1:       
        BuiltinLED.value(0) #turns LED on        
    else:        
        depth()          
        time.sleep(0.5)        
        print(WaterLevelDifference)
```

'''

I have done i2c.scan() and it shows [118,119] but sometimes intermittently. What does this error mean?

Comment: Which line of your code gives the error? Does it always give the error, or does it work intermittently?

Comment: i2c.scan() shows [118,119] but **sometimes intermittently** 
seems to indicate you have a flaky connection in your circuit